# HTML5 Video Container Appears Black

Tags: html, video, heroku, asset-pipeline, middleman

I am currently making a static site that makes use of a .mp4 video. I am using Middleman and hosting with Heroku (free plan). On my local server everything works wonderfully, but in the deployed Heroku version the video appears as a black box. In Safari and Firefox there is no container at all. All my other assets seem to be loading nicely. The video is 5.9 mb. Any idea what is going on here? Thank you in advance!!

```
<video class="vid-home" src="/videos/home.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if you do not specify a 'poster' image to display before the video starts, the browser should display the first frame of the video:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp

In practice browsers seem to implement this inconsistently, and I have seen some mobile devices cases where certain videos display the first frame and others a black box, even for the same video types.

To avoid the issue you can specify your own image to be displayed using the mechanism mentioned in the link above - this should work consistently across browsers. The HTML will look something like:

```html
<video class="vid-home" controls poster="yourImage.png" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="/videos/home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag or format.
</video>
```